system of order differential equation
write the following equations  as equivalent system first order diff. equ.
$y''+3\sin(zy)+z'=\cos t$ and $z'''+z''+3y'+z'y=t. $
My attempt
let $x_1=y$, $x_2=y'$. Now,
$x_1'=x_2$,
$x_2'=-3\sin(zx_1)-z'+\cos t$
Also, let $x_1=z$,$x_2=z'$, $x_3=z''$. Now,
$x_1'=x_2$
$x_2'=x_3$
$x_3'=t-x_1y-3y'-x_2'$.
Is that correct?

If you have used $x_{1}, x_{2}$ for $y, y$, you can't then also use $x_{1}, x_{2}$ for $z, z'$.

@MatthewCassell two different equations . Right?

Yes, exactly. Rather, set $x_{3} = z, x_{4} = z', x_{5} = z''$.

We are given the following system and want to write it as a system of first-order equations.
$$\begin{align} y''+3\sin(zy)+z'&=\cos t \\z'''+z''+3y'+z'y&=t\end{align}$$
We let
$$y_1 = y, y_2 = y', y_3 = z, y_4 = z', y_5 = z''$$
We can now rewrite the system as
$$\begin{align} y_2' + 3 \sin(y_3 y_1) + y_4 &= \cos(t) \\ y_5' + y_5 + 3 y_2 + y_4 y_1 &= t \end{align}$$
Writing this as a first order system, we have
$$\begin{align} y_2' &= -3 \sin(y_3 y_1)- y_4 + \cos(t) \\ y_5' &= -y_5 -3 y_2 -y_4 y_1 + t \end{align}$$
We need the following initial conditions
$$y_1(0) = y(0), y_2(0) = y'(0), y_3(0) = z(0), y_4 (0)= z'(0),y_5(0) =  z''(0)$$

I just found this , but it does not have an accepted solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3392348/write-two-differential-equations-as-an-equivalent-system-of-first-order-equation?rq=1.

Moo, Thank you for your solution. But why we need the following condition

You need five initial conditions as you need two for the first and three for the second. For example, when we have an equation as $y' = ...$, we need one IC. For $y'' = ...$, we need two ICs and so on. Generally, an n th order differential equation should have at least n initial conditions in order to get a particular solution.

Here is a more mathematical rationale why: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2966606/number-of-initial-conditions-required-to-determine-unique-solutions-to-odes

Here is another reference: https://www.quora.com/How-many-initial-or-boundary-conditions-have-an-nth-order-differential-equation-Can-a-differential-equation-have-only-boundaries-or-initial-conditions
